# Error using Spring Boot with ActiveMQ Artemis and MQTT

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I am using Spring Boot with embedded ActiveMQ Artemis, and I am adding `artemis-mqtt-protocol` maven dependency. It is showing following error:

```
AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext:559] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedActiveMQ' defined in class path resource [com/els/galaxy/gateway/ArtemisConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManagerFactory.stripPasswordParameters(Ljava/util/Map;)V 
[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:597] - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'readPersistenceUnit' =
[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean:597] - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'writePersistentUnit' 
[session:167] - node0 Stopped scavenging 
[ContextHandler:1045] - Stopped o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@7bebe5de{application,/galaxy-gateway,[file:///C:/Users/basireddym/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-docbase.7636853341168462882.86/],UNAVAILABLE} 
[AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer:102] -artemis
```

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as such to help users who have this same question in the future. If not, please clarify why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the version of `artemis-mqtt-protocol` you're using is newer than the version of the broker. Therefore, there is code in the MQTT protocol handler that is trying to call a method which doesn't exist in the broker (since it's an older version). The method in question (i.e. `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.MQTTProtocolManagerFactory.stripPasswordParameters(Ljava/util/Map;)V`) was added in Artemis 2.8.0 so if the broker you're using isn't at least that new then this will fail.

Please ensure the version of `artemis-mqtt-protocol` you're using is the same as the broker's version from Spring Boot.